# Can Nsight Systems use debug info URLs?

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight, nsight-systems

So I am on Arch Linux and the libraries from the official repositories do not ship with debug symbols. To work around this in most debugging tools, one can use `DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.archlinux.org` as an environment variable (e.g. `DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.archlinux.org valgrind ./myApp`). I tried adding that environment variable both before launching nsys-ui and in the "Environment variables" section of "Collect CPU IP/backtrace samples", but both do not seem to add any debug symbols for system libraries.

Therefore I end up with loads of unresolved symbols as can be seen in the "Top-Down View". [image: unresolved symbols]

As can be seen here there is a "Symbol locations..." option but that only allows adding local paths.
[image: "Symbol locations..." option]

Is it possible to add the debug symbols via a debug info URL in Nsight Systems?

Specs: Nsight Systems 2022.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for Linux, it is not currently possible to resolve symbols from symbol servers.

Answering the question more broadly, symbol resolution from servers is available for Windows.
You can also refer to [Symbol Resolution](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#symbol-resolution-troubleshooting) at the Nsight Systems Documentation for more information.

To request features for Nsight Systems, please send feedback via the GUI (Help -> Send Feedback), or create a post at the appropriate forum category, [https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/development-tools/nsight-systems](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/development-tools/nsight-systems/116).

Comment: Thank you. I submitted the Feature Request from Nsight Systems. Maybe this will work in the future.